# C++ Error 1 error C2227: left of '->keyPress' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++-2008

Hi I am having trouble with my code. I got error C2227.

My code:

**Game.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include "drawEngine.h"
#include "Sprite.h"


class Runner
{
public:
    bool run();



    Runner(){};
protected:
    bool getInput(char *c);

    void timerUpdate();
private:
    int *gamer;
    double frameCount;
    double startTime;
    double lastTime;

    int posX;



    drawEngine drawArea;
};

#endif
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "drawEngine.h"
#include "Character.h"
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
//this will give ME 32 fps
#define GAME_SPEED 25.33
bool Runner::run()
{

    drawArea.createSprite(0, '$');
    gamer; new Character(&drawArea, 0);


    char key = ' ';

    startTime = timeGetTime();

    frameCount = 0;
    lastTime = 0;

    posX = 0;

    while (key != 'q')
    {
        while(!getInput(&key))
        {
            timerUpdate();
        }

        gamer->keyPress(key);
        //cout << "Here's what you pressed: " << key << endl;
    }

    delete gamer;
    cout << frameCount / ((timeGetTime() - startTime) / 100) << " fps " << endl;
    cout << "Game Over" << endl;

    return true;
}

bool Runner::getInput(char *c)
{ 
    if (kbhit())
    {
        *c = getch();
        return true;
    }
}

void Runner::timerUpdate()
{
    double currentTime = timeGetTime() - lastTime;

    if (currentTime < GAME_SPEED)
        return;


    frameCount++;

    lastTime = timeGetTime();
}
```

I've never seen this before.
I've looked everywhere for an answer but they don't work with my code. I've got other code too that belongs to the same project which I didn't post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 int *gamer;
```

to

```
 Character* gamer;
```

and

```
 gamer; new Character(&drawArea, 0);
```

to

```
 gamer = new Character(&drawArea, 0);
```

Comment: it gives me a new error: C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'Character *' to 'int *'

Comment: Ah you need to declare the Character class before the Runner class - add a line "class Character;" just before it in game.h

Comment: ..or include Character.h before Game.h in Game.cpp if there are no other dependencies

Comment: sorry I didn't see that comment

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you've defined `gamer` as

```
int *gamer;
```

So when you write

```
gamer->keyPress(key);
```

You're trying to call a member function on an `int`, which is not legal.

Are you sure you want `gamer` to be an `int *`?  That seems incorrect.

Comment: it gives me a new error: C2541: 'delete' : cannot delete objects that are not pointers

Comment: @Blackelfwolf- What did you change it to?  Make sure it's a pointer if you're trying to `delete` it.

Comment: @Blackelfwolf- I think you need to sit down and rethink your design.  Don't just try making small changes like this.  If you're trying to use `gamer` as something that can respond to `gamer->keyPress(key)`, what type should it be?  Take some time to think about what all the pieces of your design should be; just trying to make it compile by making these localized changes will obscure the high-level design issues and probably leave you with a very nonfunctioning system.

Comment: I'm actually doing this through a tutorial called Evil Monkeys on the 3d Buzz website.